# MusicBot - adding a command to post pictures from PC

Tags: python, discord

I'm not confident with my programming abilities and have been searching high and low to find answers. I've checked the discord api server and also spend 2 days Google Searching before making an account here to seek help.

### I'm using MusicBot as a base for my personal bot.

I'd like to add a command that lets me post a random picture from an assigned folder on my computer.
Currently, I have this code:

```
def cmd_lood (self, channel):
        my_path = r"C:\My Pictures\Saved Pictures\Pixiv Dump" 
        choice = os.path.join(my_path, random.choice(os.listdir(my_path))) 
        return self.send_file('choice','Channel')
```

Upon launching the command in Discord, I get an error in the CMD stating:
InvalidArgument: Destination must be Channel, Privatechannel, User, or Object. Received str

Can I seek some assistance in getting this bot to successfully work in posting a picture from my PC please?
Thank you very much for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

[`send_file(destination, fp, *, filename=None, content=None, tts=False)`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.send_file)

So, channel must be first argument and must be [`discord.Channel`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Channel) object or [`discord.PrivateChannel`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.PrivateChannel) object. File path or *file-like object* must be second arg. You can use [`discord.utils.get`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) to get channel by it's name.

And you used string "choice", not variable

So, correct code must look like this:

```
    def cmd_lood (self, channel):
        my_path = r"C:\My Pictures\Saved Pictures\Pixiv Dump" 
        channel = discord.utils.get(self.get_all_channels(), name=channel)
        choice = os.path.join(my_path, random.choice(os.listdir(my_path))) 
        return self.send_file(channel, choice)
```

I also recommend to use command extension to have context on commands, because the way with getting channel with `self.get_all_channels()` can return wrong channel if bot can get access to more than one channel with this name.

With command extension this code will looks like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

...

bot = commands.Bot()

...

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def cmd_lood (ctx, channel):
     my_path = r"C:\My Pictures\Saved Pictures\Pixiv Dump" 
     channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.server.channels, name=channel)
     choice = os.path.join(my_path, random.choice(os.listdir(my_path))) 
     await bot.send_file(channel, choice)
```